# How to pass urls as user input to invoke through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, user-input

Every time I run my script I want it to ask me what is the targeted url using input() so it can store it as a variable and use it in a function but every time I input the url the script won't continue and pressing enter causes it to open the url on my default browser as a tab instead of a new chrome object.

```
def function1(targeturl):
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get(targeturl)

print('What is the website?')
webPage = input()
function1(webPage)
```

I'm not sure whether the IDE is important but I'm using Pycharm. I will copy and paste the url in after it asks me and when I press enter it will open the url instead of continuing the script

Comment: it is really a welknown bug in pycharm , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57070719/why-does-pycharm-automatically-hyperlink-my-url/57071362#57071362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke a *url* taken as user *input* you can use the `input()` function.

Here is your own program with some simple enhancements which will accept 3 *urls* one by one from the user and navigate to the respective *urls*:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  def function1(targeturl):
      driver.get(targeturl)
      # perform your taks here

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  for i in range(3):
      webPage = input("What is the website url?(Press enter at the end to continue):")
      function1(webPage)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  What is the website url?(Press enter at the end to continue):http://www.google.com
  What is the website url?(Press enter at the end to continue):http://www.facebook.com
  What is the website url?(Press enter at the end to continue):http://www.gmail.com
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do but the script stop running because all actions are done.

Like Selenium Doc say "The driver.get method will navigate to a page given by the URL."

For example, you can add this to your function (return page title, some actions and then quit the driver):

```
print browser.title
'''
Make some actions
'''
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do like this what happens? assign "targeturl" as a global variable first.

```
targeturl = "xxxx"
def function1(targeturl):
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get(targeturl)

print('What is the website?')
webPage = input()
function1(webPage)
```